# Dual VGA Monitors to work with DVI-only slots - converter advice

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

We have a load of VGA-only LCDs which I want to connect to our thin clients which have two outputs: DVI-D and a DVI-I. The only converters I have are DVI-I (24+5) so I need to purchase VGA > DVI-D converters. These are available on eBay for about $2, however all of the high street stores are selling them at about $40, these appear to mention the word 'active'.

I am clearly missing something here, will the cheaper converters work ok or do I need active converters?

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is DVI-to-VGA, not the other way around - if I understood you correctly (usually the computer has OUTPUTS in the video signal department, not "inputs", unless I don't know something). SO it might be a good idea to correct those errors in your question...

The difference is between DVI connectors when discussing the need of active converter to VGA - if you have DVI-D output from client then you need active converter, if you have DVI-I then cheaper adapter will work.
From my experience in the topic I can tell you right now that you still should test specific devices before you'll purchase the whole lot.

Also, be aware that picture on VGA LCD will not be as sharp as you would like above certain resolutions...

Comment: Thanks. The 10Zig 5848c's have one DVI-I and one DVI-D - I will purchase a couple of the cheaper adapters to test, but the chances of them actually working are quite slim!

Comment: Not quite slim. There is the difference between DVI-D and DVI-I that accounts for the majority of the problems when converting digital to analog and quite a lot of people do not pay attention to this detail and are very quick to complain when unsurprisingly it doesn't work... I was guilty of something similar a while back... So fingers crossed and go forth and test...